# accessing MSysObjects from Access 2010 accdb-format db

Tags: perl, odbc, ms-access-2010

Windows XP Pro
ActiveState Perl 5.14.4
M$ Access 2010

I have an Access db in accdb format which contains a number
of stored queries. I'd like to extract them to flat files using Perl.

The names of the queries appear in [MSysObjects].[Name] while the queries
themselves appear to be stored in the MSysQueries somehow.

But my problem is upstream from that - I can't read either of these tables.
I've confirmed when I open the db directly the username is "Admin".

Googling turned up http://t1134.codeinpro.us/q/5080f5c04f1eba38a4d1547b ,
which explains "Admin" does not have SELECT permission to MSysObjects so I need
to execute a DDL statement to GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin

More googling turns up http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010 , which says
to enable certain administrative statements like GRANT I need to add 
    Uid=Admin; Pwd=; ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;
to my connection string

And that same page has a blurb to specifically state where the workgroup file is
located
    SystemDB=C:\mydatabase.mdw
in the connection string.
More on this in a moment.

So I've got this

```
#! /home/gnu/bin/perl
#

package main;

use strict;
use autouse 'Data::Dumper' => qw(Dumper);
use DBI;
use DBD::ODBC;    # works for both access and sql server
use Win32::ODBC;
use OLE;
use Win32::OLE;

# prototypes
sub _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_EnableAdminStatements($);
sub setPermissionsOnTables($);
sub readTableMSysObjects($);

#globals
my $debug = 1;

my $targetDbFile  = undef;
my $dbh_C = undef;

print "version of DBD::ODBC   is ".$DBD::ODBC::VERSION."\n";
print "version of Win32::ODBC is ".$Win32::ODBC::VERSION."\n";
print "version of Win32::OLE  is ".$Win32::OLE::VERSION."\n";

$targetDbFile  = "C:/putyer/msaccessdb/here.accdb";

$dbh_C = _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_EnableAdminStatements( $targetDbFile);

setPermissionsOnTables( $dbh_C);
readTableMSysObjects( $dbh_C);

$dbh_C->disconnect() if( defined( $dbh_C));

exit(0);
#-------------------------------
#  when you use perl to open an .accdb  Access database the Uid is always Admin
#  But user Admin doesn't have SELECT permission on MSysObjects by default you must first
#  grant the permission on the object for the user
#  to enable certain admin commands like CREATE USER, GRANT, REVOKE, DEFAULTS when using CREATE TABLEs
sub _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_EnableAdminStatements($)
{
  my ( $dbFile) = @_;

  my $errorHit = 0;

  my $conn_str = "DBI:ODBC:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};dbq=".$dbFile;
  $conn_str   .= "; Uid=Admin; Pwd=; ExtendedAnsiSQL=1";

  my $dbh = DBI->connect( $conn_str);
  if( !defined( $dbh)) {
    print "db connection failed - ".$DBI::errstr."\n";
    $errorHit = 1;
  }

  print "connection _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_EnableAdminStatements failed\n" if( $errorHit);

  return $dbh;
}
#-------------------------------
sub setPermissionsOnTables($)
{
  my ( $dbh) = @_;

  print "entering setPermissionsOnTables\n" if $debug;

  my $errorHit = 0;

  my $q   = undef;
  my $sth = undef;

  unless( $errorHit) {
    $q = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($q);
    if( !defined( $sth)) {
      print "sth failed to define - ".$DBI::errstr."\n";
      $errorHit = 1;
    } else {
      $sth->execute();                        # <===  FAILS HERE
      if( my $errorMsg = $dbh->errstr ) {
        print "select statement failed - ".$errorMsg."\n";
        $errorHit = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  unless( $errorHit) {
    $q = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysQueries TO Admin";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($q);
    if( !defined( $sth)) {
      print "sth failed to define - ".$DBI::errstr."\n";
      $errorHit = 1;
    } else {
      $sth->execute();
      if( my $errorMsg = $dbh->errstr ) {
        print "select statement failed - ".$errorMsg."\n";
        $errorHit = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  print "exiting  setPermissionsOnTables with errorHit=".$errorHit."\n" if $debug;
  return $errorHit;
}
#-------------------------------
sub readTableMSysObjects($)
{
  my ($dbh) = @_;

  print "entering readTableMSysObjects\n" if $debug;

  my $errorHit = 0;

  my $q   = undef;
  my $sth = undef;

  unless( $errorHit) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM MSysObjects";  # remember that db nulls come over as perl undefs
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($q);
    if( !defined( $sth)) {
      print "sth failed to define - ".$DBI::errstr."\n";
      $errorHit = 1;
    } else {
      $sth->execute();
      if( my $errorMsg = $dbh->errstr ) {
        print "select statement failed - ".$errorMsg."\n";
        $errorHit = 1;
      } else {
        if( $sth->rows == 0 ) {
          print "select statement returned 0 rows\n";
          $errorHit = 1;
        } else {
          my $row_hashref = undef;
          while( $row_hashref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
            print Dumper( $row_hashref);
          }
        }
      }
      $sth->finish();
    }
  }

  print "exiting  readTableMSysObjects\n" if $debug;
  return $errorHit;
}
```

which fails when attempted to execute the first GRANT with the infamous 
    Cannot open the Microsoft Access database engine workgroup information file
message.

So it appears I need this file too, which I can't seem to find on my box.
Or could/should I use a different connection? Like one of these?

```
#-------------------------------
sub _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_ADO_ACE($)
{
  my ( $dbFile) = @_;

  my $errorHit = 0;

  my $conn_str = "DBI:ADO:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=".$dbFile;
  $conn_str   .= "; Persist Security Info=False";
# print $conn_str."\n";

  my $dbh = DBI->connect( $conn_str);
  if( !defined( $dbh)) {
    _pushErrorMsg("db connection failed - ".$DBI::errstr);
    $errorHit = 1;
  }

  print "connection _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_ACE failed\n" if( $errorHit);

  return $dbh;
}
#-------------------------------
sub _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_ADO($)
{
  my ( $dbFile) = @_;

  my $errorHit = 0;

  my $conn_str = "DBI:ADO:File Name=".$dbFile;

  my $username = undef;
  my $password = undef;

  my $dbh = DBI->connect( $conn_str, $username, $password);
  if( !defined( $dbh)) {
    _pushErrorMsg("db connection failed - ".$DBI::errstr);
    $errorHit = 1;
  }

  print "connection _setUpDatabaseHandle_Access_Local_ADO failed\n" if( $errorHit);

  return $dbh;
}
```

Any pointers/hints/constructive critisms and especially examples are all welcome.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that the Access Database Engine and related drivers seem to have access to the [MSys...] tables locked down pretty tightly in ADO and OleDb. They seem to still be accessible via DAO, but if you're using DAO then you don't really need to fuss with [MSysObjects] because you can just iterate through the `QueryDefs` collection.

The following VBScript dumps the SQL code for each Query into a separate text file. You could integrate it into your Perl project either by

- porting the code to Perl (and using whatever mechanism(s) are available in Perl to manipulate COM objects), or
- shelling out from your Perl script and running the VBScript itself (via `cscript.exe`).

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim dbe  ' As DAO.DBEngine
Dim db  ' As DAO.Database
Dim qdf  ' As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fso  ' As FileSystemObject
Dim f  ' As TextStream

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  ' New FileSystemObject
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")  ' New DAO.DBEngine
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\__tmp\main.accdb")
For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\__tmp\" & qdf.Name & ".sql")
    f.WriteLine qdf.SQL
    f.Close
    Set f = Nothing
Next
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set dbe = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and example! I'll be giving it a try in the next day or so.